# Your web page contains the meta tag "viewport" twice. You should remove the second meta tag, even if it is embedded in an iframe HTML tag

Tags: meta

My web page http://beachsandchairs.com/ contains the meta tag "viewport" twice.

Beach Chairs  extra comfort at beach -outdoor beach chairs

How true is that because of this search engines could regard it as a spamming attempt and not index my site? 
Could the second meta tag be remove without creating a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [viewport meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) tag is nothing to do with search engines indexing, it defines the behaviour for the display & zooming of the site on mobile devices.

It's likely that your search engine ranking is already being reduced due to your website not being responsive for small screen sizes.

You can see both of the tags in your HTML source code:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

It's up to you how you want to define the ability to zoom your website, or resize to fit content.